# Convert operator from string type to operator type

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I want to generate something like this at random.

> 233 + 333 = 566

I mean the first number and the operator and the second number are generated at random.

So, I wrote this code now.

```
var x = parseInt(Math.random()*1000),
    y = parseInt(Math.random()*1000),
    operators = ['+', '-', '*', '/'],
    operatorNum = parseInt(Math.random()*4),
    operator = operators[operatorNum],
    result;

result = x + operator + y;
```

But this just gives me something like `"748/264"` as a string.
It doesn't give me the result of the calculation generated.

I suppose I need to convert operator from string to operator type.
But, I don't think there is a operator type.

**Edited**

I'm building a Chrome extension. As per the Chrome extension policy, I'm not allowed to use the `eval` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Evaluate it:

```
result = eval(x + operator + y);
```

---

EDIT

Since you can't use eval, you need to build your own math functions. You can just specify the four functions inside that array (if you don't actually need to know their names), like:

```
myFunctions = [
    function(a, b){return a+b;}, 
    function(a, b){return a-b;}, 
    function(a, b){return a/b;}, 
    function(a, b){return a*b;}
];
```

Then just randomly pick one and call it with your x and y variables as parameters, just like you did before: `result = myFunctions[parseInt(Math.random()*4)](x, y);`.

Comment: oh Thank you so much. But I'm sorry that I miss mentioning that I'm building a Chrome extension and I'm not allowed to use eval function.

Comment: Chrome gives me an error if I use eval function within the program.

Comment: You're welcome. Hmmm, I guess you need to build your own basic math functions (multiply, divide, add and subtract) and use them instead. So, in the end you'll have something like: `result = randomChosenFunction(a, b);`

Comment: Thank you very much. I see. I need to build my own math functions.
@Blender gave me the hint, so try to make it work! Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, though you can just specify the four functions inside that array (if you don't actually need to know their names), like: `myFunctions = [function(a, b){return a+b;}, function(a, b){return a-b;}, function(a, b){return a/b;}, function(a, b){return a*b;}];`. Then just randomly pick one and call it with your x and y variables as parameters, like this: `myFunctions[parseInt(Math.random()*4)](x, y);`

Comment: oh nice! Thank you very much for your advice. I'm learning a lot now.

Answer (score 10):

There are no built-in operator functions in JavaScript, but you can make your own pretty easily:

```
var operators = {
    '+': function(a, b) {
        return a + b;
    },
    '*': function(a, b) {
        return a * b;
    },
    ....
};
```

And then call the appropriate operator:

```
operators['+'](4, 7);  // 11
```

But here, you can just use `eval` and treat your string as JavaScript code:

```
eval('2 + 2');  // 4
```

Comment: Oh this seems the answer I need for my situation. I missed mentioning I'm building a chrome extension and I'm not allowed to use eval function. So, it seems that I need to build my own math function like you show me.

Comment: I'll try to work like you show me. I need to go out now, so after I'm back, I'll get back to this problem. Thanks!!

Comment: @crzyonez777 You can get eval to work in a Chrome extension by adjusting the CSP, see https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#relaxing-eval.

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution here is to use [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

```
result = eval(x + operator + y)
```

In this case it is safe to use eval, but [Be warned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don.27t_use_eval.21) - It is a [dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea) function to use

Comment: Seems pretty harmless here since there's no user input to worry about.

Comment: @j08691 was just directing the user to the dangers of `eval()` in this case it is pretty safe

Comment: Thanks! I'm sorry that I missed mentioning I'm building a chrome extension and I'm not allowed to use eval function in any way.

Comment: @crzyonez777 in that case go for Blender's solution