# Javascript - calculation including either "*" or "/" gives me a wrong answer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a javascript code that generates a calculation formula at random.

The code generates something like these at random.

134 + 333 = 467

10 * 3 = 30

9 / 3 = 3

130 - 20 = 110

In order to generate something like these, I have this code as shown below.

```
var myCal = [
    function(a, b){return a + b;}, 
    function(a, b){return a - b;}, 
    function(a, b){return a / b;}, 
    function(a, b){return a * b;}
];

var tempX = parseInt(Math.random()*1000),
    tempY = parseInt(Math.random()*1000),
    tempNum = parseInt(Math.random()*4),
    result;

result = myCal[tempNum](tempX, tempY);
```

But, the problem is that when it generates calculation formula including either "*" or "/", it returns wrong answer.

For example, when tempX is 393 and tempY is 334 and operator is *, it returns 1.1766467065868262.

What's causing this problem?

I have no clue of what's wrong with it.

Please help me out if you know how to solve this problem.

Thanks!!

**P.S**

Since I'm building a Chrome extension, I'm not allowed to use the eval function by their security policy. That's why I have my own myCal function.

Comment: Nice to see you used my code but not selected my answer. And btw. `393 / 334 = 1.1766...` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18679876/convert-operator-from-string-type-to-operator-type/18679895#18679895

Comment: Some questions just make you wish we still had the "too localized" close reason.

Comment: @Shomz Hi! Yeah, I wanted to select your answer but I selected the other guy's answer already, so... :(

Comment: @crzyonez777 You can change the accepted answer, you know.

Comment: @Juhana oh, I didn't know I could do that. I changed the accepted answer now :)

Comment: Thank you. Also, I forgot to mention, be careful when dividing by zero. I know there's 1 in 4000 chance of it happening, but still, you should make a graceful fallback when it occurs.

Comment: oh thank you for your advice. I didn't think about the case of getting zero.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose the best would be to modify the division function to something like: `function(a, b){return (b == 0) ? false : a / b;}` and then work with your result variable only if it's not false. Most browsers can probably handle division by zero, but it's nicer and safer to have your own fallback and be in the full control.

Comment: _Google Chrome_ seems to define `x / 0` as `Infinity`, probably because `lim y->+0: 1 / y = Infinity`, but then `+0 === -0` so `-Infinity` is a valid answer too, so I'd say you have the choice (for `x / 0`) of using `sign(x) Infinity` or `NaN` if you wanted to be explicit but not `throw`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> For example, when *tempX* is `393` and *tempY* is `334` and operator is `*`, it returns `1.1766467065868262`.

```
393 * 334; // 131262
393 / 334; // 1.1766467065868262
```

Looks like you've mixed up your operators.

Comment: You catch it so fast!!!!