# Using variable that contains "multiply" string for multiplication of 2 other numbers

Tags: javascript

I have a task where I should create 3 variables, 2 of them will be numbers (2,3) and the 3rd will be `'*'` or `'/'` sign string. 
I need to write a function that will return the answer of `2*3` and `2/3` by using the 3 variables only for the outcome.

I have no idea how to use the variable that contains a string, and that string to perform the operation of subtract or multiply.

```
function multiply (a , b ,c ) {

}
console.log (multiply(4, (*) , 5 )) ;
```

I expect the outcome to be `4* 5` and `4/5`

Comment: Write functions that do the effect of the sign in the string and then use it depending on which sting was sent.

Comment: A rather straightforward way would be to use an if statement to check what symbol `c` is, and then perform the adequate operation based on `c`, and return the result

Comment: As Shilly said, use functions named like operators, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/18679912/1169519

Comment: In return what you expect string or number ?

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
const multiply = (num1, num2, calc) => `${num1}${calc}${num2}`


console.log(multiply(1,2,"*"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Put it on if condition and match ur sign

```
function multiply (a , b ,c ) {
  return c === '*' ? a*b :  a/b
}
console.log (multiply(4,  5, '/' )) ;
```

Hope it help

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to pass an operator as a parameter to a function, which isn't possible in javascript. You can still make this function though, but using strings as an alternative.

```js
function multiply(a, b, op) {
  if (op === '*') return a * b;
  if (op === '/') return a / b;
}

console.log(multiply(2, 5, '*')); // should return 10
console.log(multiply(2, 5, '/')); // should return 0.4
```

Comment: THAT IS IT !  Thank you  Phoenix1355

Comment: @Jefry90 if this answers your posted question, then you should consider marking it as answered. The one you've currently got marked doesn't answer the question you posted correctly

Answer (score 1):

```
const handlers = {
    '*': (a, b) => { return a * b; },
    '/': (a, b) => { return a / b; },
}

function multiply (a , b ,c ) {
    return handlers[b](a, c);
}
```

Comment: What about this code `console.log (multiply(4, (*) , 5 )) ;`

Comment: Good point, the OP seems to be saying 2 different things ha ha, you're order is fine then

Comment: He's also somehow expecting a string output